# Is there a way to set up optional arguments to bypass input arguments?

Tags: python, function, loops, arguments

Python 3: 
I am trying to set up a function to be more flexible. In its current state there are no arguments accepted when you call the function. When you call the function it asks you a series of questions that act as the guiding parameters for the function (see code). I would like to keep this functionality...

However, I would also like to be able to put in my own parameters(bypassing the question) from the onset. Is there a way to have both?

So if there is no argument put in the parenthesis next to the function, it will ask the questions, and if there are numbers/arguments in the function, it will bypass the questions and use those parameters.

I've tried various approaches such as:

```
def function_dummy(xx='', yy=''):
    xx = int(input("xx = "))
    yy = int(input("yy = "))
```

but it still asks the questions.

It's also tricky because I don't want to just set up defaults. If I'm bypassing the questions I want to be able to enter in different numbers all the time.

## currently (model, not real deal)

```
def function_dummy():
    xx = int(input("xx = "))
    yy = int(input("yy = "))
    for i in range(0,xx):
        print(yy)
```

## I would like to maintain this ^ functionality but also be able to enter it in like:

```
function_dummy(2, 3)
```

Comment: It sounds like this function has too many separate responsibilities. It shouldn't be reading user input *and* doing whatever else it does.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just mean

```
def function_dummy(xx=None, yy=None):
    if xx is None:
        xx = int(input("xx = "))
    if yy is None:
        yy = int(input("yy = "))
```